# Why does linking against static runtime libraries in Visual C++ 2008 still requires MSVCR71.dll at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm building a dll *statically* linked against the c runtime libraries. Why then does it require MSVCR71.dll at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`msvcr71.dll` is Visual C++ 2003's C runtime. If you're building with 2008, there's no reason there should be a reference to this DLL. My guess is that you depend on another DLL which was built with 2003, and which uses the dynamically linked runtime.

Comment: Oh. I'm using the JVM dll. That may be it.

Comment: Yup. Confirmed. The JVM requires it. Just a little more care and I could have avoided this questions. It's just that questions are answered so quickly here...

Answer (score 1):

You may be linking against the LIB [import library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z8kac4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the DLL - check you are using linker option `/MT` and not `/MD`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=VS.90).aspx

MSVCR71.dll doesn't look like the correct version of the runtime for VS2008. Are you linking against any other third party libraries that require the older runtime?